# Microsoft Web API Help page - how to create annotations for parameters

Tags: attributes, documentation, webapi, asp.net-web-api-helppages

Recently I've start playing with new web API help page functionality, that was recently added to web API project template, and I have a notice that some "Additional information" column is always 'none'.

[image]

After some looking at markup I found that this info should arrive from attributes

```
 <td class="parameter-annotations">
                    @if (parameter.Annotations.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var annotation in parameter.Annotations)
                        {
                            <p>@annotation.Documentation</p>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>None.</p>
                    }
                </td>
```

But what kind of attribute I should use, to populate additional information?

Answer (score 16):

See [this site](http://www.strathweb.com/2014/01/return-types-action-parameters-and-data-annotations-now-available-in-web-api-2-1-help-page/) for an example of how to add additional information.

It's basically annotating your model, so in your case it would be something like:-

```
public class Product
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The id of the product
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the product
    /// </summary>
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which would give you an output like this:-

[image: example output]