# custom additional information in API documentation

Tags: c#, documentation, xmldocument, asp.net-web-api-helppages

[image]

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098077/microsoft-web-api-help-page-how-to-create-annotations-for-parameters) about additional information of web API help page. The data annotation actually provides the additional information for documentation. But I want to know that is there anyway to provide additional information without data annotations?

If yes then how?

If not then is there anyway to override the additional information with data annotations for instance the

```
[Required]
```

shows Required written in additional information but what if I want to show "This field is required" or something like that?

Thanks

**EDIT** see in picture I want to update that additional information without data annotation if possible.

Comment: I think you are looking for alternate of Data Annotation. Then you should use Fluent API, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj591617.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give custom additional information(using data annotation) then @Pedro G. Dias's answer is your solution but if you want to give additional information without using data annotation then I am afraid that it is not possible OR you have to use some alternative procedure to do so as commented by @DynamicVariable on your question.

PS. I've debugged documentation project to check and I found that addition information is actually provided by data annotations.

Answer (score 3):

So the annotation allows you to further specify requirements, i.e if you have the following model:

```
public class MyModel {

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You seriously need a name here bro")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

}
```

You can then automatically have the validation message shown in your ASP.Net page like so:

```
@model string
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
```

So basically, you add a field for the validation message that will be populated by ASP.Net when the **Required** attribute kicks in.

Comment: alright that provides an answer for overriding the message ...
is there anyway for doing so without data annotation?

Comment: Yes, you can use ModelState.AddModelError() in your code and avoid data annotation - don't forget to tag the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: correct me if im mistaken .... im asking about Api help documentation 
i think this is for simple view and i dont need that

Comment: Tricky - if you want API documentation, why not use the standard constructs for doing that, i.e. by commenting using /// above methods, and then extracting your API documentation as outlined in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator

Comment: yes that <summary></summary> provides only the description for that property... what i need to do is provide custom additional information for properties. :(
or how can i modify that to give additional information??

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the    `Required Attribute` 
in the `ModelDescriptionGenerator.cs` 
`Areas>HelpPage>ModelDescriptions>ModelDescriptionGenerator.cs`

For example:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Must pass")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I got:
Additional information : Must pass

replace:

```
 { typeof(RequiredAttribute), a => "Required" }
```

with:

```
{ typeof(RequiredAttribute), a => {
            RequiredAttribute b =(RequiredAttribute)a;
            return (b.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

[see](http://aspnetguru.com/how-to-show-custom-validationattribute-description-in-web-api-help-page-2-1/)

Comment: Yes. :(  But u can edit the **parameters.cshtml** And edit the message.                           `foreach  (var annotation in parameter.Annotations) {<p>@annotation.Documentation</p>}`