# C# Web API Help Page - Additional Information for the Body Parameters shows "None."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am using the Microsoft ASP.Net Web API 2.2 Help Page version 5.2.3 and the additional information for the Body Parameters is showing "None".  I have not been able to make it show any useful information.  The other information is populated correctly.

Sample Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for doing something.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This text here shows fine as the Description.
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is needed!")]
    public int MyInt;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the additional information should be populated either as "Required" or as the text in the error message.  I have already tried this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920075/5910024 to no avail.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098077/microsoft-web-api-help-page-how-to-create-annotations-for-parameters?lq=1